# JPA CDI JAXB - Setter getting ignored

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, openjpa

My JAX-RS Resource is successfully getting a JPA/JAXB entity and a list of JPA/JAXB entities from a db.

One entity serves as a parent entity.  The list of entities is a field in the parent entity.  I can't set the parent entity's list to the returned list of entities.  The parent entity is returned in a JAXB parent entity, but that doesn't affect the situation.

Here's the code:

```
@Inject
InventoryService inventoryService;
@Inject
HcUser user;
@Inject
InventoryResponse inventoryResponse;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public InventoryResponse getInventory(@Context HttpServletRequest request, 
                                      @HeaderParam(IDENTITY_URL) String identityURL, 
                                      @HeaderParam(ACCESS_TOKEN) String accessToken) {

    String username = (String) request.getAttribute("username");
    user = inventoryService.getUserById(username);
    user.setHcCounts(inventoryService.getCountsForUserId(username));
    inventoryResponse.setUser(user);

    return inventoryResponse;
}
```

The returned JSON is only returning the user object.  I've tried manually instantiating a user object and setting it to the return value of the getUserById method and then calling setHcCounts with the returned list.  However, the setter is still ignored.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using WAS v8.0.0.8.  The stack is:

`JAX-RS` - Apache Wink v1.1.1 (supplied by WAS 8)

`OpenJPA` - Apache v2.1.2-SNAPSHOT (supplied by WAS 8)

`JAXB` - MOXy v2.7

`CDI` - Apache OpenWebBeans 1.0 (supplied by WAS 8)

`EJB` - Apache OpenEJB (supplied by WAS 8)

**Update 1**
Here's the InventoryResponse class as requested, however I don't think that it's necessary.  Upon inspecting the user object, on the line before `inventoryResonse.setUser(user)`, during debugging, hcCounts is null.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
@XmlRootElement
public class InventoryResponse implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private HcUser user;

    private List<HcLocation> locations;

    public HcUser getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(HcUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<HcLocation> getLocations() {
        return locations;
    }

    public void setLocations(List<HcLocation> locations) {
        this.locations = locations;
    }
}
```

**Update 2**
As requested, HcUser:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


@Entity
@Table(schema="<ommitted>", name="<ommitted>")
@Named
@XmlRootElement
public class HcUser implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false, length=100)
private String id;

@Column(nullable=false, length=1)
private boolean active;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="CREATE_DATE")
private Date createDate;

@Column(name="FIRST_NAME", length=100)
private String firstName;

@Column(name="LAST_NAME", length=100)
private String lastName;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="UPDATE_DATE")
private Date updateDate;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to HcAssignment
@OneToMany(mappedBy="hcUser")
@XmlElement
private List<HcAssignment> hcAssignments;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to HcCount
@OneToMany(mappedBy="hcUser")
@XmlElement
private List<HcCount> hcCounts;

public HcUser() {
}

public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public boolean getActive() {
    return this.active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}

public Date getCreateDate() {
    return this.createDate;
}

public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
    this.createDate = createDate;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Date getUpdateDate() {
    return this.updateDate;
}

public void setUpdateDate(Date updateDate) {
    this.updateDate = updateDate;
}

public List<HcAssignment> getHcAssignments() {
    return this.hcAssignments;
}

public void setHcAssignments(List<HcAssignment> hcAssignments) {
    this.hcAssignments = hcAssignments;
}

public HcAssignment addHcAssignment(HcAssignment hcAssignment) {
    getHcAssignments().add(hcAssignment);
    hcAssignment.setHcUser(this);

    return hcAssignment;
}

public HcAssignment removeHcAssignment(HcAssignment hcAssignment) {
    getHcAssignments().remove(hcAssignment);
    hcAssignment.setHcUser(null);

    return hcAssignment;
}

public List<HcCount> getHcCounts() {
    return this.hcCounts;
}

public void setHcCounts(List<HcCount> hcCounts) {
    this.hcCounts = hcCounts;
}

public HcCount addHcCount(HcCount hcCount) {
    getHcCounts().add(hcCount);
    hcCount.setHcUser(this);

    return hcCount;
}

public HcCount removeHcCount(HcCount hcCount) {
    getHcCounts().remove(hcCount);
    hcCount.setHcUser(null);

    return hcCount;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof HcUser)) {
        return false;
    }
    HcUser other = (HcUser) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

**Update 3**
Here's the code for HcCount:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlInverseReference;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(schema="<omitted>", name="<omitted>")
@Named
@XmlRootElement
public class HcCount implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="HC_COUNT_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="COUNT_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="HC_COUNT_ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
private long id;

@Column(name = "LOCATION_NUM", nullable = false, length = 100)
private String locationNum;

@Column(name = "PRODUCT_CODE", nullable = false, length = 100)
private String productCode;

@Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, length = 100)
private String userId;

@Column(name = "LOT_CODE", nullable = false, length = 100)
private String lotCode;

@Column(name="\"COUNT\"")
private BigDecimal count;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="COUNT_DATE", unique=true, nullable=false)
private Date countDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="CREATE_DATE")
private Date createDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="UPDATE_DATE")
private Date updateDate;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to HcUser
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
@XmlElement
@XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="hcCounts")
@Inject private HcUser hcUser;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to HcLocation
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="LOCATION_NUM", referencedColumnName="NUM", unique=true, nullable=false)
@XmlElement
@XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="hcCounts")
@Inject private HcLocation hcLocation;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to HcProduct
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_CODE", referencedColumnName="CODE_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
@XmlElement
@XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="hcCounts")
@Inject private HcProduct hcProduct;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to HcLot
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="LOT_CODE", referencedColumnName="CODE_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
@XmlElement
@XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="hcCounts")
@Inject private HcLot hcLot;

public HcCount() {
}

public long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLocationNum() {
    return locationNum;
}

public void setLocationNum(String locationNum) {
    this.locationNum = locationNum;
}

public String getProductCode() {
    return productCode;
}

public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
    this.productCode = productCode;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getLotCode() {
    return lotCode;
}

public void setLotCode(String lotCode) {
    this.lotCode = lotCode;
}

public BigDecimal getCount() {
    return this.count;
}

public void setCount(BigDecimal count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public Date getCountDate() {
    return this.countDate;
}

public void setCountDate(Date countDate) {
    this.countDate = countDate;
}

public Date getCreateDate() {
    return this.createDate;
}

public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
    this.createDate = createDate;
}

public Date getUpdateDate() {
    return this.updateDate;
}

public void setUpdateDate(Date updateDate) {
    this.updateDate = updateDate;
}

public HcUser getHcUser() {
    return this.hcUser;
}

public void setHcUser(HcUser hcUser) {
    this.hcUser = hcUser;
}

public HcLocation getHcLocation() {
    return this.hcLocation;
}

public void setHcLocation(HcLocation hcLocation) {
    this.hcLocation = hcLocation;
}

public HcProduct getHcProduct() {
    return this.hcProduct;
}

public void setHcProduct(HcProduct hcProduct) {
    this.hcProduct = hcProduct;
}

public HcLot getHcLot() {
    return this.hcLot;
}

public void setHcLot(HcLot hcLot) {
    this.hcLot = hcLot;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
    return result;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof HcCount)) {
        return false;
    }
    HcCount other = (HcCount) obj;
    if (id != other.id) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

**Update 4**
I've figured out a workaround...

```
public InventoryResponse getInventory(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @HeaderParam(IDENTITY_URL) String identityURL, @HeaderParam(ACCESS_TOKEN) String accessToken) {
    String username = (String) request.getAttribute("username");
    user = inventoryService.getUserById(username);
    List<HcCount> counts = inventoryService.getCountsForUserId(username);
    HcUser newUser = new HcUser();
    newUser.setHcCounts(counts);
    inventoryResponse.setUser(newUser);

    return inventoryResponse;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your JAXB config for InventoryResponse ?

Comment: @guilhebl - Hi.  Thanks for responding.  I updated my post.

Comment: Where is the code of HcUser (and especially its setHcCounts() method)? What's the value displayed for inventoryService.getCountsForUserId(username)?

Comment: @JBNizet - inventoryService.getCountsForUserId(username) is returning 1 HcCount object, populated by the correct field values that I'm expecting.  I'll post the code HcCount as well.

Comment: try removing the @Inject annotation from all your JPA domain classes